# react native onChangeText and onChange will give input value missing 1 character

Tags: react-native

I was wondering why there's 1 missing character every time I type on text input using `onChangeText` and `onChange` function simultaneously.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Text} from "galio-framework";

export default function UpcomingSurvey ({ navigation }) {

const [timer, setTimer]   = useState('')
const [saving, setSaving] = useState(false);
const [edited, setEdited] = useState(false);
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')


const inputChanged = () => {
setSaving(true)
clearTimeout(timer)

const newTimer = setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('inputValue: ', inputValue)
}, 2000)

setTimer(newTimer)
}



function renderUpcomingSurvey () {

<Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE }}>
                <>
                  {saving &&
                        <Block style={{flex: 1}}>
                          <Text muted size={11} style={{ textAlign: 'right'}}>Saving</Text>
                        </Block>
                  }
                  {(edited && !saving) &&
                      <Block style={{flex: 1}}>
                        <Text muted size={11} style={{textAlign: 'right', color: '#36d79a'}}>saved</Text>
                      </Block>
                  }
                </>
{!isLoading ? (
<Input
  editable={radioCustom}
  onChangeText={setInputValue}
  onChange={inputChanged}
  value={inputValue}
  right placeholder="Type your custom question here."
  iconContent={<Block />}
 />) : <Text></Text>

}
<Text muted size={12}>Free text | Your employees will see that this is a custom question</Text>
</Block>
```

When I try to `console.log('inputValue: ', inputValue)` inside `inputChanged` function will give missing one character. Example when I try to input `Text` this will give value in console `Tex` which missing character `t`.

[image: screenshot taken from android emulator]

[image: console.log]

Maybe there's a delay on capturing text value input after the `onChange` function triggers

What's the real culprit of these code?

Comment: is Text from 'galio-framework' intended? @totski?

Comment: can you share an expo snack please for the same?

Comment: Yes I'm using 'galio-framework' as my UI. @GauravRoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by assigning the `Input` `defaultValue={inputValue}` instead of `value={inputValue}`

Comment: hi it is still not working but with textInput component

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the async nature of the setState function
Try to log the input value like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(inputValue)
}, [inputValue]) //Only run when inputValue is set
```

Comment: Still dont get the complete value.